# Multiple level where clause filtering with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Say I have some filter criteria passed into my application via an array of CustomerFilter objects where I need to run a query and return the results based on those filters from a Linq to Entities query.

So in this case the customer would be passing me in an array of CustomerFilter objects over the service call.

*Filter Object:*

```
class CustomerFilter
{
    public string CustomerID;
    public int[] LocationID;
}
```

*Example Data:*

```
CustomerID    LocationID 

1             1

              2

              3

              4 

2             2 

              3 


              4
```

I can build a query filtering on the outer CustomerID quite easily as below.

*Query:*

```
    public void GetCustomerResults(List<CustomerFilter> accounts)
    {
        List<string> customer = (from a in accounts select a.CustomerID).ToList();

        var locations = ctx.Portal_SurveyLocations
                            .Where(w => customer.Contains(w.CustNum))
                            .OrderBy(o => o.LocationKey);
    }
```

So I can filter by the outer criteria but I am not sure how to filter by the multiple location IDs for each CustomerID. Obviously just putting an OR clause would give incorrect results as it would pull in other CustomerIDs with matching LocationIDs.

Any ideas of how to accomplish this multiple level filter given the CustomerFilter object passed in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Slight rework. Basically, we use a combination of `Any` to traverse the sub-collections to achieve the desired result.

```
var locations = ctx.Portal_SurveyLocations
    .Where(w => accounts.Any(a => a.CustomerID == w.CustNum &&
                                  a.LocationID.Any(l => w.LocationKey == l)))
    .OrderBy(o => o.LocationKey);
```

Comment: It doesn't compile due to, I think, a scope problem with the lamba expression on the LocationID.Any w                     
A local variable named 'w' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'w', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something

Comment: @mattytommo I adjusted your code since you were trying to use a variable called `w` in 2 different scopes: You had it for the `Where` lambda as well as the `a.LocationID.Any` one, and so it was generating @PhilMurray's compiler error. I believe this should remedy the problem.

Comment: Hey, you're the one who nailed the answer to OP's question. It's only fair that you get the benefits of it.

Answer (score 0):

For fast lookup (using `Contains` on a `List` isn't very fast) you can create a dictionary of hash sets from the filter objects.

The dictionary would contain one item for each customer, and the value in that item would be a hash set of the locations. When using it, first you check if the customer is in the dictionary, then you check if the location is in the hash set for that customer:

```
public void GetCustomerResults(List<CustomerFilter> accounts) {
  Dictionary<string, HashSet<int>> lookup =
    accounts.ToDictionary(a => a.CustomerID, a => new HashSet<int>(a.LocationID));

    var locations =
      ctx.Portal_SurveyLocations
      .Where(w =>
        lookup.ContainsKey(w.CustNum) &&
        lookup[w.CustNum].Contains(w.LocationKey))
      .OrderBy(o => o.LocationKey);
}
```

Both the dictionary and the hash set have an `O(1)` complexity for looking up an item, so the entire operation gets an `O(n+m)` complexity, where `n` is the number of filters, and `m` is the number of items in `Portal_SurveyLocations`.

Comment: Would this map directly into Linq to Entities?